# Javascript Time - Run a Function every Half Hour

Tags: javascript, datetime

I made this function that does two things: returns the amount of time until the next thirty minute mark, and calls the halfHour function when the timer reaches zero. If the time was `12:06:27`, output would be `24:33` (mm:ss)

```
function checkTime() {
  var time = new Date();
  var mins = time.getMinutes();
  mins = (60-mins) % 30;
  var secs = time.getSeconds();
  if (secs != 60){
  secs = (60-secs) % 60;
  } else {
  secs = 00;
  }
  time = [Number(mins),Number(secs)];
  if (mins == 0 && secs == 0){
    halfHour();
  }
  return time;
}
```

This works, but there is a strange glitch. When the minute rolls over, it shows...
`24:02`
`24:01`
**`23:00`**
`23:59`
`23:58`

It also calls `halfHour();` one minute too soon, at the false `0:00` mark in the last sequence: `1:02` `1:01` **`0:00`** `0:59`

How can we correct this?

---

#### Solved

Commenters dbrin and njzk2 have the solution. It's subtracting minutes and seconds from `59` instead of `60`. Below is the modified **working code.** Sorry it's messy.

```
function checkTime() {
  var time = new Date();
  var mins = time.getMinutes();
  mins = (59-mins) % 30;
  var secs = time.getSeconds();
  if (secs != 60){
  secs = (59-secs) % 60;
  } else {
  secs = 00;
  }
  time = [Number(mins),Number(secs)];
  if (mins == 0 && secs == 0){
    halfHour();
  }
  return time;
}
```

Comment: whats your timeout code look like?

Comment: setInterval(function(){ /* code to run every half hour */ }, 30000);

Comment: The issue is in `(60-mins) % 30;`

Comment: getMinutes and seconds return 0-59 not 1-60

Comment: I'm working with Node.js, and my script requires it specifically be ran on the half hour mark. I have node running this function with a `setInterval` every second.

Comment: Note `mins` and `secs` are already numbers. No need to use `Number`

Comment: at time `12:07:00`, there are exactly 23 minutes (30-7) and 0 seconds left. at `12:07:01`, there are 22 minutes and 59 seconds. You cannot measure the minutes and seconds separately.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel when JavaScript has a built in  setInterval(code, delay); to acheive this.

```
setInterval(function() {
    alert("I will fire after every 2 seconds")
}, 2000);
```

Comment: that's not relevant to the question.

Comment: that might not be relevant, but it improves the whole code in question and not just addresses the issue.

Comment: It is not guaranteed, that the function will be executed exactly after 2 seconds. So if you want to return the exact time, you should always calculate it, even inside the interval callback.

Comment: I have this kind of code in another part of my script, calling this function.

  `var updater = setInterval(function() { checkTime();},1000);`

Comment: @defau1t: there is no scheduling in the posted code. for all you know, it could be called using `setInterval(checkTime, 1000)`

Comment: My function specifically gets the time until the minute hand hits 12 or 6 on an analogue clock, no matter when the script was fired.

Comment: @user14351: you could nest the function and use closure to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

The way you measure the time is flawed. The number of minutes and the number of seconds cannot be considered separately, as I showed in my earlier comment.

An easier way is to start by measuring the total number of seconds, and then format it:

```
var time = new Date();
var totalS = 60 * ((60 - time.getMinutes()) % 30) - time.getSeconds()
var secs = totalS % 60
var mins = (totalS - secs) / 60
```